# Hibernate - Setting a cascade persist just for one session

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, cascade, persist

I have this relation in Hibernate:

```
    n      1
A   ------->   B
```

The cascade types in the `@OneToMany` from A to B is not CascadeType.PERSIST, and cannot be made so. The `@ManyToOne` from B to A doesn't have CascadeType.PERSIST either.

Now I have the case where I have a new unpersisted A referring a new unpersisted B which refers to the unpersisted A.

Persisting A leads to the exception, that A referes to the "null or transient instance" B, of course. Persisting B beforehand leads to the same error, because A is not persisted.

How do I solve this? Can I specify a one-time-Cascade-persist?

Comment: Which version of Hibernate do you use and how exactly are your classes mapped?

Comment: Hibernate 3.1, classes mapped by JPA annotations.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any cascading set up on the `one-to-many` part, the only way I can think of is to create and persist A first.. and then you can create and add Bs into the persisted A.

Any particular reason why you do not want to set up the cascade in this bidirectional relationship?

Comment: I don't want to set up cascade, because this is a very special case.